# Removing Multi-Collinearity Reduces F1 score

Tags: logistic, classification, multicollinearity, precision, f1

I was trying to build a classification model and I found that the features were highly correlated. 
I tried run a random forest model on the features and got an F1 score of 0.44 but when I removed the MultiCollinearity using VIF I saw that my F1 score reduces to 0.28. 
 What could be the possible reasons for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, random chance is always a possibility (especially without knowing more details - e.g. if you have a really small training and test dataset, then randomly changing anything may have just about any effect). I.e. it may not mean anything.

Secondly, multi-collinearity is not much of an issue for prediction models. It generally just indicates that some variables contain different information and may not add all that much value once one of the other multi-collinear ones ist included. However, it may still be that there are some small differences that still have value for predictions. To some extent, one just has to try this out (with cross-validation or a hold-out set - I assume you did that, and the F1-score is not just on the training data). Multi-collinearity is primarily an issue, if you are trying to interpret contributions (e.g. regression coefficients in logistic regression) from different similar predictors (these then become highly unstable and very hard to interpret).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

Height and body weight are highly correlated. With both, you can predict BMI perfectly.

If you drop body weight, then your prediction of BMI will get much worse.

Even though the variables are linearly correlated, that doesn't mean the two variables are completely redundant, especially if the target variable has a nonlinear relationship to the input features.